# Maven: Create plugin variable with default-value from another class?

Tags: variables, maven, parameters, global-variables, default-value

I have a plugin that I'm creating and it has a parameter like so:

```
/** 
 * Global variable as maven plugin parameter
 * @parameter expression="${plugin.var}" default-value=OtherClass.GLOBAL_VAR
 */
private int var;
```

I have another class called `OtherClass` that has a `public final static int GLOBAL_VAR;`.

How would I be able to set the default-value from a variable from the actual plugin software?

Comment: What about assigning `OtherClass.GLOBAL_VAR` directly to `var`? When you don't declare a `default-value`, `var` should not be changed when `${plugin.var}` is not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just omit the declaration of a default value and assign `OtherClass.GLOBAL_VAR` directly to `var`:

```
/** 
 * Global variable as maven plugin parameter
 * @parameter expression="${plugin.var}"
 */
private int var = OtherClass.GLOBAL_VAR;
```

As long as `${plugin.var}` is not defined, `var` will not change its value.